# Opening PDF in 3rd party app causes TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android

I have the following code snippet that should open a PDF in an external app:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(path));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This opens the PDF in Adobe Reader, however my app also crashes with the `TransactionTooLargeException` exception.

By the looks of it I am only sending the file URI and type via the intent, therefore the 1MB limit other answers from StackOvrflow doesn't really apply.

The stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 20439376 bytes
at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4211)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 20439376 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:628)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:4132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4203)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question and post the entire Java stack trace associated with this exception. Perhaps it is occurring somewhere else (e.g., tied to your saved instance state `Bundle`) that simply happens to occur as a result of calling `startActivity()` here.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and the PDF data thing is a red herring (supported by the fact the PDF opens successfully while the app its launching from crashes.)

In my case, the error occured becuase I was trying to store too much data in the activity onSaveInstanceState bundle.  I got a stack trace very much the same at the op's.